# Listing directories which contain only pdf files

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I’d like to access and show all the device directories that contain only pdf files

```
plt.ready().then(() => {
  this.listDir(this.fileNavigator.externalRootDirectory, '');
});
```

This is my list dir method:

```
listDir = (path, dirName) => {
   this.fileNavigator
     .listDir(path, dirName)
   .then(entries => {
     this.items = entries;
   })
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I'm able to list all the directories but not the directories that contain pdf's

Please help me out on this. Thank You...!

Comment: where is file navigator ionic native plugin in in ionic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listDir = (path, dirName) => {
   this.fileNavigator
     .listDir(path, dirName)
   .then(entries => {
     this.items = entries;
   })
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```